# Relative pack URI not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a couple of images in an Img folder on my project and all those images are set to Build Action: Resource.

I used to refer to all those images with relative URIs, like this:

```
new Uri("Img/image.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

I'm not sure whats changed, but it suddenly stopped working and the images are not found.
I now have to refer them like this:

```
new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Img/image.png");
```

In order for them to work. I can't figure out why did relative paths suddenly stopped working. (Relative paths are still working in the XAML)

Comment: Can you try to see if this works - `new Uri("/Img/image.png", UriKind.Relative);`?

Comment: Also, have you recently changed the assembly for the image resources and moved them to different project? In case yes then you have to use Pack URI's for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image files with build action `Resource` must be referenced by Pack URIs.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly):

> Resource files are configured as MSBuild Resource items and are
>   compiled into assemblies. WPF supports the construction of pack URIs
>   that can be used to identify resource files that are either compiled
>   into the local assembly or compiled into an assembly that is
>   referenced from the local assembly.

WPF automatically adds the prefix `pack://application:,,,` (or `pack://application:,,,/`) to image URIs in XAML. When you write

```
<Image Source="/Img/image.png"/>
```

WPF automatically converts it into the local assembly pack URI

```
"pack://application:,,,/Img/image.png".
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the same behavior for the code behind in WPF, so that relative urls will also be automatically converted into pack urls?

Comment: @Clemens - `new Uri("Img/image.png", UriKind.Relative);` works for me even from code behind without any PACK Uri. Copy to Output directory is set to Do not copy and build action is set as Resource.

Comment: @RohitVats Maybe, but it isnt't meant to work. WPF resource files have to be accessed via Resource File Pack URIs. If it works otherwise, than just by accident. At least you can't rely on such a behaviour.

Comment: @Clemens - I don't think so it's by accident. Even MSDN sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.urisource(v=vs.110).aspx) show usage without Pack URI's as well.

Comment: @Clemens - At the bottom of the linked page, usage is shown from code as well which works. Actually I have been using them for quite a time now and never face issue in it. So, was just curious for OP's problem statement because it always works for me.

Comment: @RohitVats Ah, I missed that (because my page setting was C++, not C#). Still I would recommend against that usage. Even if it's really great, not *everything* in MSDN is correct. Simple rule: use absolute pack URIs in code.

Comment: @Clemens - Agree everything in MSDN is not correct always. So, can you cite a problem OR link that why to use them is discourage in code and not in XAML. I was asking this because have never come across the statements you stated in answer. (Just out of curiosity) :)

Comment: @RohitVats Actually I can't. And of course it is not really "by accident" that a relative URI works with a resource file. Surely the WPF developers have created this automagic behaviour intentionally. But it is nowhere documented. When WPF documentation on MSDN refers to resource files, it says that they are accessed by absolute pack URIs, that simple. Think about it the other way round: a relative URI is relative to *something*, but what is that? Is it the application's current directory, or the startup directory, or a pack URI prefix, or does it even depend on what kind of resource is

Comment: addressed by the URI? That's simply to vague, at least for my personal taste.

Comment: As per my understanding it's relative to current executing assembly because if I try without pack URI and resources are there within same assembly of usage it works fine but as soon as I moved the usage to separate assembly BOOM, have to restored to Pack URI's. So, yes I buy your point of using Pack URI's. Was just want to know if it's documented anywhere. As you say it's not, so fair enough.